# Problems with AndroidManifest when trying to run PhoneGap APP

Tags: android, xml, cordova, android-manifest

), Im trying to run my first PhoneGap APP and I followed the steps on this page:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/getting-started-with-phonegap-in-eclipse-for-android.html

It seems I did all the stuff OK, but when I try to run as Android App on eclipse I get the following error:

[2013-01-21 13:13:02 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for C:\Users\Inaki\workspace\AppPrueba\AndroidManifest.xml: El tipo de elemento "manifest" debe ir seguido de una de estas especificaciones de atributo: ">" o "/>".
[2013-01-21 13:13:02 - AppPrueba] Error in an XML file: aborting build.

It's in Spanish, so translated basically says that "manifest" must be followed by ">" or "/>". I did the manifest modifications specified on the tutorial, I guess since I don't know about XML I must have mess up something. Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.appprueba"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" 
<supports-screens                        /*this line eclipse displays the error*/
android:largeScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:smallScreens="true"
android:resizeable="true"
android:anyDensity="true"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
>

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" 
        android:name="com.example.appprueba.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity 
        android:name="org.apache.cordova.DroidGap" 
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"> 
        <intent-filter></intent-filter> 
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: you didn't close _manifest_ tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.appprueba"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<supports-screens
android:largeScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:smallScreens="true"
android:resizeable="true"
android:anyDensity="true"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" 
        android:name="com.example.appprueba.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity 
        android:name="org.apache.cordova.DroidGap" 
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"> 
        <intent-filter></intent-filter> 
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

**supports-screens** should be part of a manifest content and not act as a some kind of manifest attribute.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was due to the Huawei libraries not being updated.
Take a look at here: [After updating Gradle to 7.0.2, Element type “manifest” must be followed by either attribute specifications, “>” or “/>” error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68575710/1363087)