# After updating Gradle to 7.0.2, Element type “manifest” must be followed by either attribute specifications, “>” or “/>” error

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest, manifest

So today I updated Android Studio to:

```
Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1
Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7583922, built on July 26, 2021
```

An I got a 'Android Gradle Plugin can be upgraded' notification.

Until now, I was using:

```
Android Gradle Plugin: 4.2.2
Gradle: 6.9
Java: 8
```

However, after upgrading I got the error of the question.

My Manifest File looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.hsd.contest.spain.clover.huawei">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <receiver
            android:name=".AlarmReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity
            android:name=".ConsumeActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:taskAffinity="" />
        <activity android:name=".MapActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SetTimeActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ActivityAddFreq"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ConfigActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Do you have any ideas about why this is happening?
Interesting fact: This error only happens in this project.

**EDIT** My Huawei APIs dependencies are the ones that follow:
**Module build.gradle**

```
implementation 'com.huawei.agconnect:agconnect-core:1.5.0.300'
implementation 'com.huawei.hms:awareness:1.0.7.303'
implementation 'com.huawei.hms:ml-computer-vision-ocr:2.0.5.300'
implementation 'com.huawei.hms:ml-computer-vision-ocr-latin-model:2.0.5.300'
implementation 'com.huawei.hms:ml-computer-vision-ocr-cn-model:2.0.5.300'
implementation 'com.huawei.hms:location:5.0.4.300'
implementation 'com.huawei.hms:maps:4.0.0.301'
implementation 'com.huawei.hms:site:5.0.5.301'
implementation 'com.huawei.hms:hianalytics:5.0.3.300'
implementation 'com.huawei.hms:ads-lite:13.4.41.304'
```

**Project build.gradle**

```
classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.4.2.300'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error is due to Huawei outdate libraries.
I followed instructions here to update to latest version:
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-apm-android-releasenotes-0000001052887266

It is important to follow the notice:

> NOTICE Since version 1.5.2.302, the APMS plugin capabilities have been
> integrated into the AppGallery Connect plugin. To update the SDK
> version to 1.5.2.302 or later, you need to complete certain
> configurations to ensure compatibility with the original plugin
> functions. For details, please refer to the version change history of
> version 1.5.2.302.

I also have to change

```
implementation 'com.huawei.agconnect:agconnect-core:1.5.2.307'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.huawei.agconnect:agconnect-core:1.5.2.300'
```

For some reason (unknown to me) version 1.5.2.307 couldn't be found.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, because it explains the "why".

Comment: Thank you. also updating to `classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.9.1.300'` has resolved the problem

Answer (score 20):

The real solution I found by using trial and error version to use is

```
implementation 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.5.2.300'
```

Comment: Worked by adding your line to module's build.gradle and changing the version too at the project's build.gradle. However, I'm still puzzled Android Studio doesn't tell me this library is outdated and blames everything on a fake syntax error. Is there any way to know the latest Huawei AGCP version?

Comment: @xvlaze I just used intuition I didn't find a commonplace with version listing so I figure maybe they fixed it in the patch lane. But maybe there is a place we just don't know.

Comment: After updating `com.huawei.agconnect:agcp` to the latest version, the error does not appear anymore! Thank you for your solution! 
Best

Comment: I think you can check this version list: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-apm-android-releasenotes-0000001052887266

Comment: For me this is added in gradle but need to upgrade to latest version and it will work

Answer (score 4):

Encountered the same problem. Update Huawei services. Please take care.
Remember to keep your dependencies on the most up-to-date version.
This problem is happening on Merged-Manifest.

```
implementation 'com.huawei.agconnect:agconnect-core:1.4.0.300'
```

please use. -> 1.5.0.300

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I wento to AppGalleryConnect and redownloaded agconnect-services.json, but nothing happnede. Gradle, plus, is not telling me any of my Huawei dependencies is outdated. For information purposes, I'm attaching the line in which AGConnect Core is installed:

```implementation 'com.huawei.agconnect:agconnect-core:1.4.0.300'```

Comment: Thanks! But unfortunately it's still not working.

Comment: That also didn't help us we do have the same problem. Is there any solution ?

Comment: Edit and redefine the manifest tags in all your modules in a text editor.

Comment: You mean typing them by hand?

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: I added the fix below since the version is not correct.

Answer (score 3):

same problem, updated to latest available version and it worked

```
classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.6.0.300'
```