# Flutter project fails to build after adding huawei agconnect

Tags: android, flutter, push-notification, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-push-notification

After adding 'com.huawei.agconnect' plugin my flutter project fails to build:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong: Execution failed for task
> ':app:processDebugResources'.  failure occurred while executing
> com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
>
> > Android resource linking failed
> > C:\Users\denbo.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\2f7fef5146433a886db0a4b7a0dabd3c\push-5.1.1.301\AndroidManifest.xml:9:5-11:55:
> > AAPT: error: resource attr/??? (aka com.example.app:attr/???) not found.

my android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.61'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.4.2.301'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/' }
    }
}
```

android/app/build.gradle

```
//stuff
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.huawei.agconnect'
```

Comment: Can you specify how you added agconnect plugin?

Comment: i added the plugin according to https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides-V1/integrate-plugin-0000001050418527-V1

Comment: can you try my fix https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68575710/after-updating-gradle-to-7-0-2-element-type-manifest-must-be-followed-by-eith/68588930#68588930

Comment: @PedroAGSantos i tried your fix and it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had cyrillic characters as a label for my application in AndroidManifest.

```
<application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="АБВГ"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon">
```

After changing this to

```
<application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="ABCD"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon">
```

I am able to build my app.